# Simple, catchy French equivalent of “you have it backwards!”

Tags: expressions, anglais

In English, you can use this colloquial expression, as in:

> Tu dis que **je** ne **te** fais pas confiance ?!
>
> ***You have it backwards (there)!***

Le locuteur entend par là que

> Au contraire, c'est **toi** qui ne **me** fais pas confiance !

By using the expression “you have it backwards”, you can avoid verbosity, for one thing. I’m looking for its French counterpart.

Unfortunately, « au contraire » *by itself* does not work here, as it is more like:

> Oh que non, j’ai une confiance absolue en toi !

By saying “you have it backwards”, we expect the two elements in the previous sentence to be swapped/switched/shuffled around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a couple colloquial alternatives I can think of:

> T'as tout faux
>
> C'est tout l'inverse

In this context you could also use

> Tu parles, au contraire !

Or "tu rigoles", "tu plaisantes", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a l'équivalent exact en français « prendre les choses à l'envers ».

> Tu prends les choses à l'envers.

On peut avoir des variantes selon les cas :

> Tu retournes / inverses la situation.

Answer (score 3):

Dans le cas soumis, "tu prends les choses à l'envers" ne marche pas. On l'emploierait plus en réponse à quelqu'un qui analyserait un problème ou une situation plus abstraite, pas pour retourner une critique directe.

Oralement la réponse la plus évidente serait "C'est plutôt l'inverse  ! " (ce qui sous-entend "c'est plutôt toi qui ne me fait pas confiance")

("C'est tout l'inverse" a quant à lui le sens de "Au contraire, je te fais entièrement confiance. On a besoin du "plutôt", qui donne la notion de renversement.)

Answer (score 1):

Dans l'exemple soumis, je dirais juste:

> C'est l'inverse!

sans ajouter "tout".